# Why is my Moq not returning null?

Tags: c#, moq

My Moq is returning data I don't expect.

```
var artist = new Artist();
artist.Id = "4576";
var deserializer = Mock.Of<IXmlDeserializer<Album>>(
    d => d.Deserialize("foo").Artist == artist);
Assert.IsNull(deserializer.Deserialize(null));
```

The above test fails.

The really puzzling thing is that the mock returns a Mock but that

```
Assert.AreEqual("4576", deserializer.Deserialize(null).Artist.Id)
```

returns true.

It's as if the "default" returned by my mock for an unspecified argument (in this case null) was somehow influenced by what I told it to return when called with "foo".

Answer (score 1):

You can either write:

```
var artist = new Artist { Id = "4576" };
var mock = new Mock<IXmlDeserializer<Album>>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Deserialize(It.Is<string>(i => i == "foo"))).Returns(new Album() { Artist = artist });

var deserializer = mock.Object;

Assert.IsNull(deserializer.Deserialize(null));
Assert.IsNotNull(deserializer.Deserialize("foo"));
```

Or using the Mock.Of() syntax the above would be:

```
var artist = new Artist { Id = "4576" };
var deserializer = Mock.Of<IXmlDeserializer<Album>>(d => d.Deserialize(It.Is<string>(i => i == "foo")) == Mock.Of<Album>(album => album.Artist == artist));

Assert.IsNull(deserializer.Deserialize(null));
Assert.IsNotNull(deserializer.Deserialize("foo"));
Assert.AreEqual("4576", deserializer.Deserialize("foo").Artist.Id);
```

Comment: Changing `(d => d.Deserialize("foo") == ...)` to `(d => d.Deserialize(It.Is<string>(i => i == "foo")) == ...)` makes no difference.
If I run the code you posted the first Assert.IsNull fails.

Comment: Nevermind - the fix is about specifying a predicate on the returned object and not one of its properties. Raised https://github.com/moq/moq/issues/19

Comment: You also need to Mock the return value `Deserialize(...) == Mock.Of<Album>(album => album.Artist == artist)` Should I put that on 2 lines for better readability ?